# How to make separate form for a moderator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

Suppose, I have a simple form in edit.slim template. Like the following

```
= simple_form_for article, method: :put do |f|
  = f.input :title
  = f.input :body
  = f.button :submit
```

But what If I want it to be different for a different role?
For example, how can I have one form for a member and extended one for a  moderator?

Moderator should have one more inpur field `= f.input :status, as: :select`

Comment: What does a moderator form have in addition to what a regular form has?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just check role (sorry for Erb instead Slim):

```
<% if current_user.is_moderator? %>
    <%= simple_form_for ... %>
    <!-- moderator form content -->
<% else %>
    <%= simple_form_for ... %>
    <!-- common form content -->
<% end %>
```

or if common users and moderators can use same form:

```
<%= simple_form_for ... %>
    <!-- common form content -->
    <% if current_user.is_moderator? %>
        <!-- moderator form content -->
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

If moderator's form contains required fields, use first variant or add `f.hidden_field`:

```
<% if current_user.is_moderator? %>
    <%= f.input :status, as: :select %>
<% else %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :status, value: some_default_value %>
<% end %>
```

**Update:**
Don't forget check moderator rights in backend as [Rich Peck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1143732/rich-peck) advises

Comment: The last option seems to be appropriate for my case. I'll try this out.

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient way is to use the following:

```
= simple_form_for article, method: :put do |f|
  = f.input :title
  = f.input :body
  - if current_user.moderator?
    = f.input :moderator_input
  = f.button :submit
```

This would need to be backed-up in the controller with the appropriate checking:

```
#app/controllers/articles_controller.rb
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
   def create
     params = current_user.moderator? ? "moderator_params" : "user_params"
     @article = Article.new eval(params)
   end

   private

   def user_params
     params.require(:article).permit(:x, :y)
   end

   def moderator_params
     params.require(:article).permit(:x, :y, :z)
   end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Users model, create a column for admin and set the default to false. Then you can control what parts of the form are displayed for

```
@user vs @user.admin
```

or you can specify that only an @user.admin can approve images or only the @user.admin can delete topics or only an @user.admin can vote up/down etc

Comment: But how do you exactly control what parts of the form displayed for a different role?

Comment: By using <% if %>  <% else %>  <% end %> .  From  a security perspective, you should be creating actual rules that prevent non-moderators from editing/posting those fields. otherwise, for example, what if you one day make a mistake in your views and the forms are displayed, now they can do whatever it is you don't want them to be doing.